# Airflow database migration job is failing

Tags: airflow

I am trying to deploy airflow on our kubernetes cluster in our aws environment. We are using the official [HELM chart](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/index.html) airflow provides for this task.

When deploying the migrateDatabaseJob is started, but I can see that its quickly failing with a problem that can only be caused by a bug in the airflow source code I suppose:

```
[2022-03-25 09:27:17,567] {cli_action_loggers.py:105} WARNING - Failed to log action with (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "log" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO log (dttm, dag_id, task_id, event, execution_dat...
                    ^
 
[SQL: INSERT INTO log (dttm, dag_id, task_id, event, execution_date, owner, extra) VALUES (%(dttm)s, %(dag_id)s, %(task_id)s, %(event)s, %(execution_date)s, %(owner)s, %(extra)s) RETURNING log.id]
[parameters: {'dttm': datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 25, 9, 27, 17, 506252, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')), 'dag_id': None, 'task_id': None, 'event': 'cli_upgradedb', 'execution_date': None, 'owner': 'airflow', 'extra': '{"host_name": "airflow-run-airflow-migrations-x7t6v", "full_command": "[\'/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow\', \'db\', \'upgrade\']"}'}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)
DB: postgresql://<db>/airflow?sslmode=prefer
[2022-03-25 09:27:18,510] {db.py:919} INFO - Creating tables
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/storage/common/_connection.py:82 SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
```

But it may also be the case that there are some problems with the custom dependencies we want to install into our airflow docker image:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.2.4-python3.9

USER root
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install build-essential -y \
    && apt-get install unixodbc-dev -y \
    && apt-get install libkrb5-dev -y
USER airflow

RUN pip install pipenv
COPY Pipfile /

RUN pipenv install --system
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction, I am quite lost on this issue at the moment, because it doesnt seems to be a configuration issue with the HELM chart. The connection to our external Postgres database seems to be working. It's seems to be a problem in the airflow source code itself.

Comment: I have same issue. looks like database migration job never even gets created. so the db lacks all default tables - eg `log` and thus the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all the people who are having the same problem: The Airflow HELM chart seems only to be working with the standard tags e.g. `2.2.4`and not `2.2.4-python3.9`. This means that you have to use `python3.7` (which is used by the standard tags) for running your DAGs.

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue and was wondering if you have a source (e.g. a Github Issue or Discussion) for this.

Comment: No unfortunately I dont have one, because I was quite unsure if it really is a bug due to @Jareks answer, but he didnt provide any feedback to me so I guess it makes sense to create one

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer is wrong. Helm chart works similarly for -python images as well (adding this here so that the answer does not mislead passers-by).

Comment: Is it working for you? What is the issue with how I am using the airflow image then?